# ERROR: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement' ? Typescript can't find my div?

Tags: html, typescript, getelementbyid

Learning Typescript and trying to build a simple textbox that displays the text once submitted.

Am able to capture the input great and and now trying to report it back to the user.

The problem is on compilation typescript gives this error message: 
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'.

Am simply trying to assign the value of the div messageList to print the array (don't care about formatting yet).

I have been searching the web and most I can find says it must be naming error, i tried changing the name to 1 and still no joy.

Have attempted to use general HTML element in the cast but no joy.

The TS code:

```
let messages = [];

class Message {
  content: string;
  constructor(
    public message: string
  ){
    this.message = message
  }
}

function post(message: string){
  var text = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("messageInput")).value;
  const newPost = new Message(text)
  messages.push(newPost.message)
  console.log(messages)
  this.report(newPost)
}

function report(message: Message){
  (<HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("messageList")).value = messages
}
```

the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Typescript Messages</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="messageInput" type="text" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
    <button id="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="post()">Post</button>
    <div id="messageList" value="">Hello rubhy</div>
    <script src="message.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: `value` is not a valid attribute of `div`. You might want to use `data-value` if you're trying to actually put some information inside of the div tag itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function report(message: Message){
  (<HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("messageList")).value = messages
}
```

You need to cast it as HTMLInputElement as you done with `text` in `post` function:

```
function report(message: Message){
  (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("messageList")).value = messages
}
```

The HTMLDivElement type doesn't have the `value` property, so that's why you get that error.

EDIT: I just saw that messageList is a `<div>`. Div cannot contain a `value` property. For custom properties, use `data-*`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!